# How can I capture/handle client-side window.location changes in HtmlUnit?

Tags: javascript, htmlunit

I'm using **HtmlUnit** to unit test a jQuery-based application that makes heavy use of JavaScript, including client-side changes to `window.location`. For example, I might have an `onClick` event for a button similar to:

```
var newUrl = window.location + "?someParam=blah";
window.location.assign(newUrl);
```

(A bit more complicated than that, since the code deals with whether the param already exists. Trying to simplify for this example.) Then in my unit testing code, I might do:

```
HtmlPage newPage = buttonObject.click();
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);
String url = newPage.geturl().toString(); // always the original URL, not the new one
```

It never seems to load the new page; the `window.location` changes seem to just get ignored. I've read some posts on the interwebs saying that HtmlUnit just doesn't support client-side `window.location` changes, and other posts indicating that it can be "hacked," but I haven't found out how to hack it.

Does HtmlUnit support `window.location` changes, or does anyone have an example of where they've hacked it to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding of the API.
Like in a real browser the window it the part that stays when the (window.) location is changed by javascript. The page inside the window gets reloaded - means the page inside the window is replaced with a new one.

```
// newPage is the page loaded from the server
HtmlPage newPage = buttonObject.click();

// the js running in the backround might replace the window.location with a new value
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);
```

But the java object newPage is still pointing to the old page because the new page was loaded from the window.
You have to ask the  window for the current content (current page).

```
HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage) newPage.getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the original code posted actually *does* work the way I'd have wanted it to work. (Even without the call to `getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosingPage()` that was suggested.) When the HtmlUnit code was simplified to the point that it was shown in the example code, it worked. So this is an invalid problem.